# What is information form of Kalman filter? How is it better or different from standard form?

Tags: kalman-filter

I don't understand what is unique about information matrix or information form of Kalman filter. What is so unique or different about it from the standard form?

Answer (score 3):

The information matrix is the inverse of the covariance matrix.  A covariance matrix is symmetric positive definite and therefor has a unique inverse, called the information matrix.  Kalman filters can be implemented using either form.

One reason to select an information matrix implementation in preference to a covariance matrix implementation is that an information matrix initialized to zero implies no information (infinite variance) on each of the states.  One cannot initialize a covariance matrix that way - some finite variance must be selected.

Information matrix processing decreases the complexity of measurement processing and increases the complexity of covariance propagation - but they are mathematically equivalent for a linear system.  Some discussion on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Information_filter